# The type org.apache.http.Header cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: android

**error log:**

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.apache.http.Header. Fix the build path then try building this project

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are compiling against Android 6.0 (SDK 23), you need to include org.apache.http.legacy library.

In Android Studio add

```
 android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

to build.gradle.

In Eclipse copy `org.apache.http.legacy.jar` from `AndroidSDK/platforms/android-23/optional` to libs folder.

Comment: Same issue for AQuery which solved by doing above stuff.